# Varnish set upstream proxy for backend

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, varnish

```
backend default {
    .host = "external.site.com";
    .port = "80";
}
```

From the varnish server, I need to contact the backend via a proxy. How to add one?

There is nothing like `.proxy = "";` in the backends configuration or?

I tried defining  `.host = "my-proxy-ip";` and setting `req.http.Host = "external.site.com";`, to use the proxy as backend and force the `Host` header but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

My first try by setting the proxy as a backend, instead of the final server itself was correct:

```
backend default {
    .host = "my.proxy.com";
    .port = "8080";
}
```

But it was not sufficient to rewrite the `Host` header. The `req` object itself must be rewritten:

```
set req.url = "http://external.site.com" + req.url;
```